# Why doesn't C# VS2017 intellisense work with var and local functions?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, intellisense, var, c#-7.0

Why doesn't Intellisense work if I do something like this.

[image]

It does work though if I explicitly declare `Foo`

[image]

Comment: Sometimes Intellisense just breaks.  Try restarting Visual Studio and rebuilding your project.  It might be necessary to fix all compilation errors before the problem gets resolved.

Comment: @Paolo Go, If you get any latest information,feel free to share it here. Of course, if any reply is helpful for you, you could mark it as the answer, so it could also help other community members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem reproes. It is a problem with parsing incomplete code.

The line that you started (`foo.`) gets parsed together with the local function on the line below. This causes the local function not to be parsed correctly, so VS doesn't know that `GetFoo` is a local function any more or that it returns a `Foo`.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a bug in visual studio. As a work around, you can get the intellisense to play nice in this situation by declaring GetFoo at the top of your function's scope.

```
void Test()
{
    Foo GetFoo() => new Foo();

    var foo = GetFoo();
    foo.DoThing();

}
```

[image: Intellisense Working]

I observe the same behavior you have when placing the `GetFoo` declaration below the point in which I'm trying to use it, so it would seem that order matters.